# How can I hide a sheet on load of spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

I wanted to know where should I write the code to hide a sheet?
Is there a onload() event? I am new to g-script

Comment: Have you tried onOpen()?

Answer (score 0):

The [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) trigger is what you are looking for:

```
function onOpen() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetToHide = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("HiddenSheet")
  sheetToHide.hideSheet();

}
```